# Why didn't Jesse kill this character

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad, el-camino-a-breaking-bad-movie

Spoilers alert.

When Todd takes Jesse out from his cage to 'help' him dispose the dead body of his cleaning lady out in the desert, Jesse gets a golden opportunity to kill Todd when he gets hold of his gun. Jesse always hated Todd right from the point when he shot the kid in the desert to him being caged and then killing Andrea. Keeping all that aside, it would make perfect sense to kill Todd just for his own freedom. Also, there were no witnesses out there in the desert. It was a perfect escape.

But he doesn't kill him and instead settles in for a pizza and cold beer on the ride back to his cage. Why in the name of good God would Jesse do that?

Initially, I thought it must be inertia; that Jesse is too used to his caged lifestyle that he doesn't like the idea of freedom; that the cage is now his reality; that he has made peace with it and with Todd. But later in the timeline of Breaking Bad, he actually does kill Todd by choking him to death and fleeing in the car roaring his freedom. What changed after? Why did he choose a pizza and beer instead of his freedom?

Comment: The title should be edited to avoid spoilers.

Comment: @GendoIkari It seems that a character *isn't* killed at some possible time in the film wouldn't be that big a spoiler. But...I haven't seen the film either.

Comment: Just knowing that Todd is alive and in the film is a pretty big spoiler for those of us who have seen all of Breaking Bad but not the new movie.

Comment: @GendoIkari IMHO there's very little surprising about the characters making appearances in flashbacks in this movie.

Comment: @bcdotweb Yes but the title of the question implied that it wasn’t just a flashback. I hope I’m wrong because it means nothing was spoiled.

Comment: I thought the scene was reminiscent of the scene in Game of Thrones where the awful Ramsay Bolton allows the guy he broke to shave him -- he felt completely safe, not even worried about an accident while shaving.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Breaking Bad*** already showed us that Jesse was broken by the gang, hence him failing to kill Todd now even when he has the opportunity.

It is even explicitly stated in an earlier scene in this movie that if Jesse tries anything, then Todd will need to visit Brock. Todd's death or disappearance would inevitably cause the same.

[As Alan Sepinwall writes](https://www.rollingstone.com/tv/tv-recaps/el-camino-breaking-bad-movie-recap-895354/):

> So when Jesse takes Todd’s gun out of the glove compartment, we know he won’t shoot the pasty monster and make his escape. Suspense isn’t just dependent on surprise, though, but on context and execution. That scene is unbearably tense not because we think Jesse might pull the trigger, but because we know he won’t, and can’t stand to see how or why.
>
> Once, in the original series, Jesse described Gale as a problem dog who had to be put down. Several seasons later, Walt objected to Skyler describing Jesse as a rabid dog who needed the Gale treatment. Here, Jesse isn’t a problem, and he isn’t rabid. **He’s just a dog who’s been broken by a cruel, unyielding master who isn’t afraid of that gun, because Todd knows his little pet could never use it against him. Jesse has the ongoing threat against Brock to think about, but beyond that, Todd has just relentlessly ground down his humanity into paste.**
>
> The part of Jesse Pinkman that would be capable of pulling the trigger, driving back to Albuquerque to warn Brock, and heading for parts unknown has temporarily left the building. The ongoing trauma of enslavement has left him a shell of the outlaw he once tried to be. It’s terrifying and heartbreaking to watch, even as we know that Jesse eventually chokes the life out of this son of a bitch.

Comment: This is completely like the "shaving" scene in GoT where Ramsay shows that the guy he broke can be trusted to hold a razor at his throat. However, despite never having been tortured nor on the opposite side, is there any evidence that this is real? A torturee might act docile, but I'd like to think that when the chance for vengeance or at least escape occurs, the chance would be taken. Torture might extract information but that it turns someone completely trustworthy I think comes from fiction.

Comment: @releseabe "Torture might extract information" The opposite is true. The tortured will do or say whatever is necessary to stop the torture, whether that's a lie or the truth.

Answer (score 6):

> But he doesn't kill him and instead settles in for a pizza and cold beer on the ride back to his cage.
>
> Why did he choose a pizza and beer instead of his freedom?

I feel like you've very much misread Jesse's response. He is in tears because he realizes that anything other than acquiescing to Todd will mean Brock's death. He doesn't *settle* for beer and pizza, he doesn't *want* to go back. But he has to do what Todd says if Brock is to survive.

This is emotional torture at its finest. Jesse is so broken that even with a clear path to freedom, his emotional attachment to Brock is keeping him in that cage almost voluntarily. And it breaks him when he realizes that (which happens seconds before he hands the gun back).

Todd pointed this out right when Jesse is let out of the cage: any misbehavior leads to Todd visiting (i.e. killing) Brock. If Jesse kills Todd, Brock will simply be visited by another gang member.
Yes, Jesse could've hidden Todd's body as they were already in a prime location, but as long as the gang returns to the hideout and Jesse (and Todd) is missing, Brock will still end up dead.

> But later in the timeline of Breaking Bad, he actually does kill Todd by choking him to death and fleeing in the car roaring his freedom. What changed after?

Walt killed the gang, so there was no one to go after Brock anymore.

Even if a handful of members survived, they would be on the run and laying low. The odds of them deciding to kill Brock at that point is next to none. Jesse's escape isn't the most pressing issue for them anymore.

Comment: You're right. I actually missed out the Brock part. But come to think of it now, Jesse could have killed Todd, took his money (he knew it was hidden inside those books) and rescued Brock by the time the gang members came to know and then go into hiding. Don't you think?

Comment: @Tunic: And then Brock has to live a life on the run with Jesse. That's not a great life for Brock either. And even if Jesse were to simply rehome Brock, the gang could always find him (however they found him the first time) unless you'd set up a new identity for the kid, which again is a massive impact on Brock's life. None of this is impossible but it is still negatively impactful on Brock and nigh impossible to pull off without causing severe issues down the line.

Comment: I agree his concern is that they will kill Brock, not that Jesse has been rendered docile. When all the nazis are dead Brock is not in danger so killing Todd makes complete sense from every standpoint: vengeance and incidentally making sure Brock was safe -- not to mention Jesse himself: no way Todd could be left alive and no reason to leave him alive. Todd was an amazingly bad guy, without a normal conscience despute his lowkey, smiling behavior.